# sync images in Adobe Camera Raw

Tags: photo-editing

Is it okay to try to sync 120 images for star trails in ACR (level and increase exposure) or will that over-load the program putting all those files in at once?

Comment: A lot depends on the configuration of the machine you're using. Processor speed, memory size, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Opening and processing 120 images with same changes will NOT overload ACR.  It is built for that. I routinely open 50 to 200 files in ACR.  Then when "Done", what it saves is the small 8 KB XMP files. The large raw files are never modified. Then when you output the 120 final JPG, that might take a few minutes.

Comment: "The large raw files are never modified.", unless you use DNG. If you use DNG, the metadata is changed in the DNG file itself, unless you go out of your way to prevent this.